# Error message showing when page load

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

the Invalid code message is showing when my page loads. Even though I haven't submit the html form. It should come out when I submit the invalid code through the html form. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("test", $con);
if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('Database error!' . mysql_error());

}
else{

$row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM discount_code WHERE disc_code IN('" .implode( "','", $dc_array )."')") or die(mysql_error()); 


if (mysql_num_rows($row) == 0){
echo 'Invalid code';
}
else{
    echo 'success';
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your code with

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {}
```

to be sure that it will be executed only after sending post request (sending form).

Of course you should also use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead of `mysql_*` and think about `prepared statements`.

Comment: what the point of `strtolower` if it is always `POST`. Also, your answer is not correct - you should not check if it is POST. you should check if you get data from the right form

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski You're right, it can be skipped without any problems. Edited.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I suppose that there is only one form because noone said that are two or more. In most cases we're using only one form per page.

Comment: Still, your answer is wrong. If I'd just request the page with POST your code would execute like form is submitted. You should always check for data that is relevant, like in other answer.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski This code has to check if there is POST request. It not validates or in other way checks sent data. It have to be done in next lines after that statement. Do you want me to provide full application code here? I don't think OP needs it.

Comment: OP wrote: `Even though I haven't submit the html form` which means there's a form and you should check that. And you know the form can be send via GET, right?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski So now you are guessing that he used GET for that form? That code from answer is enough to `check if POST form was sent`. Nothing more. It doesn't check if `one of many forms was sent` and also doesn't check if `data from selected form was sent`. Please read my answer again (especially line under `if` statement) and stop trying to show us how smart are you.

Comment: It's not about how smart I am, but how incorrect your answer is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) to make sure the form was actually submitted.

Say your form is:

```
<form action="post" "somefile.php"> 
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="text" name="password" />
  <input type="submit" name="yourSubmitFormButton" />
</form>
```

Then you can use the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['yourSubmitFormButton'])) {
  // code goes here
}
```

So, when you load the page, the isset condition will evaluate to `FALSE` and the code in the `if` block will not get executed. When the submit button is pressed, the condition will evaluate to `TRUE` and the subsqeuent statements will get executed.

Also, as it's currently written, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should escape the user inputs before inserting them in your query.

```
$dc_array = mysql_real_escape_string($dc_array);
//code
```

Better yet, stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and switch to PDO or MySQLi, and learn to use parameterized queries.